# Android AAPT Issue- While replacing new image to the resource

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

After I updated my eclipse and Android SDK I encounter some problem while pasting a file to the drawable. Actually I am trying to replace a new image in the same name. After I restart the eclipse the error went of. What is the reason and how can I avoid it. Please guide me.

```
**Log:**

Error: name expected    logo.png    /Sample/res/drawable-large  line 4  Android AAPT Problem
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm seeing the same sort of thing. It appears to be a bug in the latest release, and it's not limited to image files. I'm having similar problems with raw resources--the AAPT tries to parse anything that's pasted into the `res` folder as XML.

Rather than restarting Eclipse, you can also clear the errors by cleaning the project.

**EDIT** This was evidently fixed in more recent releases of the tools. If you are still experiencing the problem, make sure you have the latest updates of everything.

Comment: @Sniper - Interestingly, for some of my files, the error does _not_ go away when I restart Eclipse. I must clean the project. I also filed a bug report ([#41597](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41597)) because, to my surprise, I couldn't find anything about this in the bug data base.

Comment: Try ignore the Lint Error checking. Windows-Preference-Android-Lint Error Checking- Ignore All.