# How can I use the library CircleProgress?

Tags: android

i want to use library CircleProgress .
I've downloaded from the following link.
[cricleProgress](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress)
And import it into eclipse
The following errors minutes.
activity_my.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:donut_unfinished_stroke_width="5dp"
        custom:donut_finished_stroke_width="10dp"
        custom:donut_progress="70"
        custom:donut_inner_bottom_text="Loading..."
        custom:donut_inner_bottom_text_size="10dp"
        custom:donut_inner_bottom_text_color="#214193"/>

    <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
```

error

```
    Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
     error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'arc_bottom_text' in      package 'com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogressexample'  activity_my.xml /MyActivity/res/layout  line 82 Android AAPT Problem
    error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'arc_bottom_text' in package 'com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogressexample'    activity_my.xml /MyActivity/res/layout  line 73 Android AAPT Problem
```

Because of this, I created a file attrs.xml.
And the following code in it that I took from the address above
And put inside it.

```
         <declare-styleable name="DonutProgress">
    <attr name="donut_progress" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="donut_max" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="donut_unfinished_color" format="color"/>
    <attr name="donut_finished_color" format="color"/>
    <attr name="donut_finished_stroke_width" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="donut_unfinished_stroke_width" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="donut_text_size" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="donut_text_color" format="color"/>
    <attr name="donut_text" format="string"/>
    <attr name="donut_prefix_text" format="string"/>
    <attr name="donut_suffix_text" format="string"/>
    <attr name="donut_background_color" format="color"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

but give error

```
         Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
      error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'donut_inner_bottom_text_color' in package      'com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogressexample'   activity_my.xml /MyActivity/res/layout  line 14 Android AAPT Problem
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add this line in your parent `view` xml layout file.

```
  xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928061/android-aapt-issue-while-replacing-new-image-to-the-resource) for AAPT error in eclipse which give more idea to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

look at ***declare-styleable name="DonutProgress"***, bro. There is no attribute *donut_inner_bottom_text*.

DonutProgress only has *prefix_text* and *suffix_text*

Answer (score 0):

Just changed

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogressexample"
```

And don't forget to set this post as answer, if help.